# Divide numbers in specific field

Tags: text-processing, xml, numeric-data

I am looking to divide numbers inside the `PERCENT=""` field in my data that is followed by both `START_LV=""` and `END_LV=""`. I want to divide the numbers by 5 however **the numbers must be whole.** Also if the number is currently below 5 then it should be set as `PERCENT="1"`

Sample data is:

```
<VALUE MON_ID="30016" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="333" ITEM_ID="992" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="1" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="30016" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="626" ITEM_ID="993" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="1" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="30016" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="555" ITEM_ID="994" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="1" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="30016" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="1" ITEM_ID="995" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="1" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="30016" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="4" ITEM_ID="996" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="1" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="30016" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="5" ITEM_ID="997" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="1" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="30016" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="300" ITEM_ID="998" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="1" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="30016" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="350" ITEM_ID="1025" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="1" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" />
```

Should change to:

```
<VALUE MON_ID="30016" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="66" ITEM_ID="992" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="1" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="30016" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="125" ITEM_ID="993" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="1" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="30016" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="111" ITEM_ID="994" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="1" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="30016" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="1" ITEM_ID="995" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="1" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="30016" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="1" ITEM_ID="996" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="1" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="30016" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="1" ITEM_ID="997" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="1" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="30016" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="60" ITEM_ID="998" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="1" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" /><VALUE MON_ID="30016" START_LV="1" END_LV="99" PERCENT="70" ITEM_ID="1025" AMOUNT="1" GROUPING="1" DROPSET="0" ZONELEVEL="GSP" VER="200" />
```

The data is not separated by lines. Also numbers that have decimal places can either be rounded up or down, doesn't matter as long as they are whole.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the file is a well-formed XML file, you may use `xmlstarlet` to update the attribute values:

```bsh
xmlstrlet ed -u '//VALUE/@PERCENT' -x 'ceiling(. div 5)' file.xml
```

This would read the XML from `file.xml` and divide the `VALUE` node's `PERCENT` attribute's value by 5, rounding the result up.  The resulting XML document would be written to standard output, so you could simply redirect it to a new document.

You could also round down, and then correct any number that turned into zero:

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed -u '//VALUE/@PERCENT'        -x 'floor(. div 5)' \
              -u '//VALUE/@PERCENT[. = 0]' -v 1 file.xml
```

Or, only divide numbers greater than or equal to 5 and set smaller ones to 1:

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed -u '//VALUE/@PERCENT[. <  5]' -v 1 \
              -u '//VALUE/@PERCENT[. >= 5]' -x 'floor(. div 5)' file.xml
```

Note the order of the operations here: We don't want to set values to 1 just because dividing them by five made them small.

Answer (score -1):

```
tr -s " " "\n" < data | while read -r a;do if [ ${a:0:7} = "PERCENT" ];then echo -n PERCENT=\"$((${a//[A-Z=\"]} / 5 ))\"\  ; else echo -n $a" ";fi;done
```